# Sunspot searches for Rails' Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reflection, sunspot

I have a Rails app with the `Content` model. The Content model has numerous [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) children models, such as `Announcement`, `Story`, `FAQ`, etc. I need to be able to query Solr via [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) for each of the children independently and as a group.

This is the present implementation of Sunspot search in the Content model. It sets defaults for hidden and published, so only active Content is returned by Solr and accepts a `block` to allow farther search params:

```
def self.search_for(&blk)
  search = Sunspot.new_search(Content)
  search.build(&blk)
  search.build do
    with :hidden, false
    with(:published_at).less_than Time.now
  end
  search.execute

  search
 end
```

This method works perfectly for Content and will return results for Content and all the children Models. I am not particular thrilled with the name of the method, `search_for`, but can't think of anything better.

I need to be able to search by child Model, i.e. `Announcement.search_for()`. I do not want to have this method pasted into the ~10 child Models, since the defaults are going to change in the near future. What I would like is have each of the children models inherit this method, but search for the child's class, not `Content` (e.g. `Announcement` would search by `Sunspot.new_search(Announcement)`).

Is there are way to reflect the class of a class method or does this method have to be dynamically generated at runtime to pre-define the calling class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy, just pass the instance type rather than `Content`. Change first line of the function to:

```
search = Sunspot.new_search(self)
```

Where self will hold `Content` if you invoke the method by `Content.search_for` and `Announcement` if invoked by `Announcement.search_for`. That's it!